# NSTextField の初期化の方法について

Tags: macos, objective-c, swift

`NSTextField` に文字列の初期値を View が描画される前に代入する方法を教えてください。

OSX 10.10.1(Yosemite) + Xcode 6.1 + Swift 1.1 で `NSTextFiled` を利用したプログラムを作っています。NSTextField を初期化するプログラムを書こうとしたところ、次のようなエラーがでました。

**fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**

fatal error になる原因は、`NSTextField.stringValue` が `nil` であるにもかかわらず unwrap されたからだと思いますが、どこで初期化するべきか、よくわかりませんでした。

また、`NSTextField` は初期値を表示することがあまりないためか、初期値をセットするコードがうまく探せませんでした。Objective-C であれば `AppDelegate` で初期化するとの記事を読みましたが、Swift では `ViewController` でするべきという話もあり、よくわかりませんでした。

playground で次のコードを動かしてみました。

```
import Cocoa

var str = "Hello, playground"
var strnil: String! = nil

strnil = str
println("\(strnil)")
```

は特に問題なく動くようでした。ですので、ViewController や Storyboard 周りの設定が悪いのか、初期化する位置が悪いのだと想像しているのですが…
Storyboard の画面のサンプルとコードは以下のとおりです。AppDelegate はデフォルトのままです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

### ViewController.swift

```
    import Cocoa
    
    class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
        @IBOutlet weak var textField: NSTextField!
        
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
    
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }
    
        override var representedObject: AnyObject? {
            didSet {
            // Update the view, if already loaded.
            }
        }
    
        required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
            //fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
            
            super.init(coder: coder)
            
            textField.stringValue = "a string"
    
        }
    }
```

### Storyboardのサンプル

[image: StoryboardのView]

Answer (score 2):

iOS同様、`viewDidLoad()`で行えば良いと思います。
initの段階ではoutletの接続が済んでいないので、textFieldはまだ使えません。これらの準備が完了するのが、`NSViewController`の`viewDidLoad()`(10.9以前は`awakeFromNib()`)です。

なお、storyboardを使った場合、AppDelegateはstoryboard内のApplication Sceneにあるuiにしか接続できなくなりました。
uiのセットアップは、そのviewを管理する`NSViewController`でやれ、というのがappleの方針のようです。

Comment: 早速お教えいただき、ありがとうございます。
以下のように変更することで、TextFiledに文字列が代入することができました。
`override func viewDidLoad() {
super.viewDidLoad()
textField.stringValue = "a string"
}`
アプリケーションのプロセスについて大変勉強になりました。
有益かつ迅速なご回答をいただき、どうもありがとうございました。